# File Transfer using Apache MINA - Java

Tags: java, ftp, file-transfer, apache-mina

I have been working on a project, in which I have to send files from local system to my FTP-server. for this purpose I thought of using Apache MINA.

is Apache MINA can be implemented in this situation, any suggestion or help will be useful. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) is a convenient and efficient library for writing FTP clients.

They also provide a FTP client example: [FTPClientExample.java](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/examples/ftp/FTPClientExample.java)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Apache Mina for this purpose. Look for following JARs/References

```
mina-core-2.0.19.jar - For authentication purpose
slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar - For logging purpose
sshd-common-2.1.0.jar - Common functions dependent jars
sshd-core-2.1.0.jar - Common functions dependent jars
sshd-sftp-2.1.0.jar - For SFTP file transfers and creating
```

clients and connections

Some example:

```
mSshClient = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient();
 mSshClient.start();
 mConnectFuture = mSshClient.connect(mUsername,mServerAddress.getHostAddress(),mServerPort,null);
 mClientSession = mConnectFuture.verify().getSession();
 mSftpClient = new DefaultSftpClient(mClientSession);
```